# Making joins in Entity Framework with not mapped tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need help: I need to make a join with 3 tables, but one of it was not mapped by Entity Framework because is just a relational table the join I need is something like that:

```
select * 
from Promocao p
join ProdutoPromocao as pp on pp.PromocaoId = p.IdPromocao
join Produto as pr on pp.ProdutoId = pr.IdProduto
join Boteco as b on pr.botecoId = b.IdBoteco
where b.IdBoteco = 1
```

but the table `ProdutoPromocao` was not mapped, how can I do this with Entity Framework?

I thought about something like:

```
(from pr in db.Promocao
 join p in db.Produto on (pr.Produto.Select(x=>x.IdProduto)) equals p.IdProduto //this line is not working, I would need something like pr.Produto.IdProduto but it does not offer me this alternative
 join b in db.Boteco on p.BotecoId equals b.IdBoteco
 where b.IdBoteco == idBoteco
 select pr
 ).ToList();
```

Someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

```
(from pr in db.Promocao
 join p in db.Produto on (pr.Produto.Select(x=>x.IdProduto).FirstOrDefault()) equals p.IdProduto 
 join b in db.Boteco on p.BotecoId equals b.IdBoteco
 where b.IdBoteco == idBoteco
 select pr
 ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with EF, there is no need to (and in some cases like this you can't) use manual joins. Once you have navigation properties, all you need is to use them (like if they were objects) and EF will generate the necessary joins for you.

Your query should be something like this:

```
from pr in db.Promocao
from p in pr.Produto
let b = p.Boteco
... (the rest)
```